# How to concatenate message from two different functions?

Tags: function, concatenation

I am studying programming concepts in my uni as a freshman. I am having a trouble with my works.

```js
    var array = [13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];

function listAll(){
    var msg1 = "List of all values in the array: " + "<br>";
    for(var pos = 0; pos < array.length; pos++){
        msg1 = msg1 + array[pos]+ " " ;
    }
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = msg1 ;
}

function performStats(){
    var count=0;
    var total=0; 
    var msg2 = "Total number of the values in the array: " ;

    for(var index = 0; index < array.length; index++){
        total = total + array[index];
        if(array[index] < 10)
        count++;
    }

    msg2 = msg2 + array.length; 
    msg2 = msg2 + "<br/>" + "The sum of all values in the array: "+ total + "<br/>" ;
    msg2 = msg2 + "The count of all values below 10 in the array: " + count;  
    msg2 = msg1.concat(msg2);
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML= msg2; 
}

function init(){
    document.getElementById("display").onclick= listAll;
    document.getElementById("stats").onclick= performStats;
}
window.onload = init;
```

Question: Why my msg2 = msg1.concat(msg2) is not working? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because variables are scoped, You can not access it out side of its own function.

You can however change them from within another function.

A quick messy way is by making the variables global or calling another function. or even a self invoking function.

```
(function() {
    var array = [13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
    var msg1 = "List of all values in the array: <br>";
    var msg2 = "Total number of the values2 in the array: <br>" ;

    function listAll(){
        // First, no need to do this
        // var msg1 = "List of all values in the array: " + "<br>";
        
        // Another way to do a foreach on an array, I find it neater.
        // array.forEach(item => {
        //     msg1 = msg1 + item + " ";
        // });
        for(var pos = 0; pos < array.length; pos++){
            msg1 = msg1 + array[pos]+ " " ;
        }
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = msg1 ;
    }
    
    function performStats(){
        var count=0;
        var total=0; 
    
        for(var index = 0; index < array.length; index++){
            total = total + array[index];
            if(array[index] < 10)
            count++;
        }
    
        msg2 = msg2 + array.length; 
        msg2 = msg2 + "<br/>" + "The sum of all values in the array: "+ total + "<br/>" ;
        msg2 = msg2 + "The count of all values below 10 in the array: " + count;  
        msg2 = msg1.concat(msg2);
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML= msg2; 
    }
    function init(){
        document.getElementById("display").onclick= listAll;
        document.getElementById("stats").onclick= performStats;
    }
    window.onload = init; 
})();
```